# How can I in c# switch input field background color (white/red) on wait?

Tags: c#, background-color

How can I in c# switch input field background color (white/red) on wait?

I am beginner in c#, the question is probably to simple...
Any Suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Win forms? Wpf? Web?

Comment: what do you mean "on wait"?

Answer (score 2):

i don't understand what you really want. you can do something like this

you can use `Task.Delay()` for waiting

```
switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            break;
        case 2:
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            break;
    }
```

**For Window Form** in case you want to change color in every two second you can use timer control. Place this code in your waiting code

```
var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 2000, Enabled = true, };
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            this.BackColor =
                    this.BackColor == Color.Red ? Color.White: Color.Red;
```

Comment: Also, if "on wait" ends up meaning doing something on the same thread then this won't even work.

Comment: @DavidPilkington i know it is bad idea but op not clear what he meant by wait winform or webform

Comment: Hello, it's simple...
An application wait on users input (in one input field).
I want the background color of this input field switch from white to red every 2 seconds while the application wait on input (while the input field has focus).
It should stop when something else on the form has focus.
Thank you very much for answer!

Comment: anwer updated, Plese take a look at it, it is for window form

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, (without MVVM), use a TextBox as input field. Create it in your .xaml file.

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Background="Red" Margin="188,134,200.4,161.4"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In your code-behind, write this code too.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int duration = 10; //Change this number to change the total flash duration
            double interval = 0.5; //Change this number to increase/decrease the interval between color changes.

            Thread t = new Thread(() => FlashColor(duration, interval));
            t.Start();
        }

        private void FlashColor(int duration, double interval)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < (int) (duration/interval); counter++)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ChangeColor(Brushes.White));
                Thread.Sleep((int) (interval*1000));
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => ChangeColor(Brushes.Red));
                Thread.Sleep((int) (interval*1000));
            }
        }

        public void ChangeColor(SolidColorBrush color)
        {
            MyTextBox.Background = color;
        }
    }
}
```